# Error 500 on Parabola and Diffbot - Private IP disallowed

Tags: error-handling

I'm getting this error on Parabola after using a Diffbot API for extraction. It says error-500. Private IP Disallowed. What does this mean?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please see [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . You haven't provided enough informations.

Answer (score -1):

This is a Diffbot error that indicates your query string has been incorrectly parsed in some cryptic way.  Usually it means you have double-encoded your URL parameter.